# pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/var/lib/postgres/data/postmaster.pid": Permission denied

Tags: postgresql

On Arch Linux, after running the initdb command, I get the following message:

```
Success. You can now start the database using:
    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgres/data -l logfile start
```

As postgres user I attempt to start by using command above and get and error:

```
FATAL: could not create lock file "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock" no such file or directory
```

I exit to postgres user and attempt to start by the command above and get:

```
pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/var/lib/postgres/data/postmaster.pid" : Permission denied
```

Than I try the above command ran as sudo:

```
sudo pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgres/data -l logfile start
```

and get:

```
pg_ctl: cannot run as root.
```

Comment: Check ownership on `/var/lib/postgres/`.
It may be as in the same issue as in this old bug - https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/16507

Comment: What is your OS distribution? What is your postgresql server version? Why not just start it using a command like `/etc/init.d/postgresql start`, `service postgresql start`?

Comment: Arch Linux, in WSL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When starting postgres manually, that is without using the packaged startup script, you need to do what the script does:

1. create the `/run/postgresql` directory with write permission for `postgres`  and read permission for others. `/run` is typically mounted on a ram disk so it's normal that it's empty.
2. run  `pg_ctl` as the user `postgres` exclusively. Use `sudo -u postgres` if `sudo` has to be used for that.

The first error you mention is solved by #1 and the two others are solved by #2. Or just use the startup script that comes with the package for your OS, it's there to take care of these details so you don't have to learn them.

The doc at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL tells to:

> Finally, [start](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Using_units) and [enable](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Enable) the postgresql.service.

which would mean `systemctl enable postgresql.service` and `systemctl start postgresql.service`, **as opposed** to `pg_ctl [...options...] start`.

Comment: You said "Or just use the startup script that comes with the package for your OS". What startup script?

Comment: @AutonomousApps: for ArchLinux, according to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL that would mean to run `systemctl start postgresql.service` as root.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth I want to add that I had a strongly related issue just now with Postgresql 10 on Ubuntu. In fact `could not open PID file “/var/lib/postgres/data/postmaster.pid”` is what landed me here. I tried things learned here and elsewhere all to no avail, then resorted to the age old reboot. And all came good. Oh well. Can't say I learned much, or that it teaches much, other than, remember to try and reboot ...

Comment: Lol, exactly for me. The great 'Reboot' fixed it!! I was playing with everything for a couple of hours without success!